# Ionic2 Import external Js File

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ionic2

I'm trying to import an external js library, moment into Ionic 2.
I have the moment modules stored in node modules however it seems web pack is not including it in my project directory.

```
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>

</body>
```

However when I look in my browser it is not included in the node modules

[image]

I have moment installed in my nose_modules however when ionic builds it does not appear in my browser as a file

I'm using Ionic 2 and Angular 2.  My guess is that I need to specify to include it some how through the modules or web pack does anyone know how to do this?

** Edit **
Here is the ts page class

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { Users } from '../../providers/users';
import moment from 'moment';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfilePage {

    userId: number;
    user: User;

    getAge = () => {
        if (this.user) {
            return moment().diff(this.user.birthday, 'years');
        }
    }

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private usersProvider: Users) {

        this.userId = navParams.get('userId');

        usersProvider.get(this.userId).subscribe(user => {
            this.user = user;
            console.log(user)
        });
    }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do as shown below. No need to do any special things.

Please see the [**official doc here**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/).

```
npm install moment --save
```

***.ts***

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

**e.g.**

`let month = moment(date).format('MMMM');`

Comment: when my project builds it is ignoring my files in the node_modules path as shown in the picture

Comment: Just remove your whole node module folder and after that do this `npm i`

Comment: That didn't help The files exist there already but they're not being served from node.

Comment: Is this sample app? If so please put that into a git repo and let me know? I'll make it works.

Comment: thanks I was using an different version of the import syntax.

Comment: Can you please share it with us? new syntax?

Comment: I guess when it compiled there were no references to the library so they left the whole thing out. once I referenced it correctly it was all good

Comment: Oh..Yep.That can happen.Glad to see now your app is working :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!